# Problem with listing a directory to grep

Tags: command-line, grep, wc

`grep` seems broken on my machine. Reinstalling it does not help. A reboot does not help. The first two lines create a file containing arbitrary text and the input is terminated with the control-D character.

`ls -1` means list in one column. A example follows...

```
> cat > file0.txt
asdf
> cp file0.txt file1.txt
> ls -1
file0.txt
file1.txt
> ls -1 | grep f*
>
```

Before experiencing this problem I did make a mistake by invoking grep with an unmatched quote but I do not understand how this problem can survive a reboot.

Unmatched quote example...

```
ls -1 | grep 'file* | wc
```

In this example the directory listing is piped to grep which pipes to the line, word, and byte counter program `wc`.

Comment: `ls -1` does not mean list one file per column. It means list one file per line. Also the `*` in a regular expression means repeat a character any number of times (including zero times)

Comment: @KristopherIves in `grep f*` f* is expandedd by the shell to the list of all files starting with f, if any.

Comment: @SorenA Correct, but OP claims this produces no results, when it should (and does) produce a list of *all* files since it's effectively a regex that matches anything. This is why I voted to close this question as not able to reproduce.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @KristopherIves please reread. I am not mistaken about ls -1 .

Comment: @KristopherIves the first code snip is a cut and paste and it was reproducible just not by you.

Comment: `man ls` will provide you with the description `-1 list one file per line.`

Comment: @KristopherIves "list in one column" and "list one file per line" are two ways of saying the same thing. Neither is the same as "one file per column," which would indeed be an incorrect description of the effect of `-1`, but that's not what the OP said. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "OP claims this produces no results, when it..." but `ls -1 | grep f*` really *does* produce no results, when it is run from a shell in a directory whose files and their contents are as described in this question (for the reason described in [Soren A's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171490/22949)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## `grep` did not use the output of `ls` in any way.

When you run `grep f*` in a situation where your shell expands `f*` to two or more arguments, `grep` considers all but one of them as names of files to open and read. **When `grep` reads from named files, its default behavior of reading from standard input doesn't apply, so it doesn't read data piped to it from another command.**

Your `grep` program is not broken, and the behavior you have observed is the correct and expected behavior, which is why reinstalling `grep` and rebooting did not change it. Details follow.

#### `grep f*` did not pass an argument of `f*` to grep.

*`grep` never saw the text `f*`.* As [**Soren A says**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171490/22949), `f*` is a glob. Globs are treated specially by your shell. Because `f*` was not [quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting), the shell expanded it into the names of files in the current directory that start with `f`. Each such name was passed to `grep` as a separate argument. ([This kind of shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) is known variously as globbing, filename expansion, and pathname expansion.)

Based on your description, there are exactly two files that match the `f*` glob: `file0.txt` and `file1.txt`. Since those are the only two files in the current directory whose names start with `f`, the command-line arguments passed to `grep` from running `grep f*` are *exactly the same* as those passed to it from running `grep file0.txt file1.txt`. If you were to add more such files to the directory, then `grep f*` would pass more than those two filenames as arguments to `grep`, but `file0.txt` and `file1.txt` would still be included among them.

#### You piped `ls` output to `grep`, but *`grep` did not read from the pipe.*

A pipe connects the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) of one command to the [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) of the other. Like `cat` and many other commands, `grep` accepts input in two ways:

1. *You can pass it filenames as command-line arguments*, and it will read from those files. The first non-option argument to `grep` is the pattern, but subsequent non-option arguments are treated as filenames from which input will be taken.

   (You're not trying to pass multiple patterns to `grep`, but if you were, you could use the `-e` option, whose operand is always treated as a pattern.)
2. *You can pass no filename arguments*, and it will read from its own standard input. This is the situation in which it is effective to pipe to `grep`. It is only in the *absence* of filename arguments that `grep` reads from standard input at all.

   This is why it's possible to use `grep` to search one or more files, without it blocking and waiting for you to enter input into a terminal. When you pipe to `grep`, the extra input that would make no sense for `grep` to use comes from the command on the left side of the pipe rather than from your terminal. `grep` still doesn't use it, and this is a good thing.

   (You're not trying to cause `grep` to read standard input in addition to one or more named files, but if you were, you could pass it the `-` argument.)

Because you have two files in the current directory whose names start with `f`, the glob `f*` expands to two arguments. The first, `file0.txt`, is used as the *pattern*. The second, `file1.txt`, is taken to name an input file. Because `grep` is given an argument specifying an input file, the first of the two situations described above applies ("You can pass it filenames as command-line arguments"). So `grep` never reads from standard input and never uses the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 14):

The expression `grep f*` will, in your case, be expanded to `grep file0.txt file1.txt` by the shell.

Apparently there are no line with `file0.txt` in the file file1.txt.

I know that's not what you wanted, but that how it works.

```
:~$ mkdir test
:~$ cd test/
:~/test$ touch f1
:~/test$ touch f2
:~/test$ set -x
:~/test$ ls | grep f* 
+ ls --color=auto
+ grep --color=auto f1 f2
```

Comment: That's not how a pipe from ls works yet there are four upvotes as of this time.

Comment: His answer is correct and he explaining that bash shell expansion and regular expressions are different things and what the results of you using grep incorrectly are.

Comment: @H2ONaCl I updated my answer with an eample, using `set -x` (debug) to show what happens. You can try yourself ;-)

Comment: I think both of you misunderstand the pipe from ls. The files never get opened and the contents never get grepped in a valid Ubuntu. ls does not read file contents.

Comment: @H2ONaCl `grep` never reads from the pipe. `grep` only automatically reads from its own standard input when no filename arguments are passed to it. Since the shell expands `f*` into two arguments, `grep` treats one of those arguments as a regular expression and the other one as a filename to read from. Since it has a filename argument, it *completely ignores* the data piped to it. `ls` doesn't open either of the files, but its output is thrown away; in contrast, `grep` *does* open one of the files. So this answer is correct. I've added an answer that details why the output of `ls` is not used.

Comment: @H2ONaCl The OP was never trying to grep the contents of the file, they’re trying to filter the ls output.  Done correctly it would be `ls | grep ‘f*’`

Comment: @rrauenza I don't know what the OP had originally been trying to do, but `ls | grep ‘f*’` would *not* have been correct, as *curly quotes* in a shell don't achieve quoting. Besides that, it's imaginable but unlikely that the regex `f*` would do what was wanted: it matches *zero or more `f`s* appearing *anywhere in a line*. So `ls | grep 'f*'` and even `ls | grep 'f.*'` were probably not intended either. If the goal was to list filenames starting with `f`, one per line, with nothing else, that's just `ls -1 f*` (or if a shell glob can't be used, `find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'f*' -printf '%f\n'`).

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep 'f*'
```

is poor form.

```
ls f*
```

should be preferred.

When using more complex regex patterns, switch to `egrep`/`grep -E`.

While I'm here, `cat` is seldom needed.  `tac` is 100x more useful than `cat`. `cat` abuse is a serious issue on Unix-like systems. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a special character which is loosely interpreted as a new command / instruction. You want to place a `\` in front of it:

```
ls -1 | grep f\*
```

However what you probably want is to get all files starting with `f` instead of ALL the files containing an `f` so use another special character instead:

```
ls -1 | grep ^f
```

The `^` instructs grep to find lines starting with `f`.